# Which are the air accelerate and walk-through-walls commands?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38UjZEanCx0) and maybe other videos grenades and positions are explained with negative air acceleration (afaik) and walking through walls. Which are the commands to use for this? sv_airacceleration does not seem to exist in CS:GO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable no clipping, you will need to either be on a server you control (and can set `sv_cheats 1` on) or a locally hosted server.

Here's how to enable no clipping (walk through walls):

- Open the console
- Enable cheats using `sv_cheats 1`
- Type `noclip`

To turn no clipping off, type `noclip` in the console again.

Air acceleration requires a command line parameter, and this can no longer be changed inside the game. Simply edit your game shortcut or the command line parameters that Steam launches the game with and add `+sv_airaccelerate 150` - where `150` is the air acceleration value you want to use.